# Heroku instance generated missing some attributes

Tags: python, heroku

Python newbie here! I'm having trouble deploying my script on Heroku - it works fine locally, but once on Heroku it gives me this log:

```
2015-04-28T09:48:43.362570+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-04-28T09:48:47.047556+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python reddit_bot2.py`
2015-04-28T09:48:49.458189+00:00 app[web.1]: :0: UserWarning: The keyword `bot` in your user_agent may be problematic.
2015-04-28T09:48:50.075734+00:00 app[web.1]: Logging in to Reddit...
2015-04-28T09:48:58.757114+00:00 app[web.1]: Accessing Subreddit...
2015-04-28T09:48:58.757095+00:00 app[web.1]: Logging into Goodreads API...
2015-04-28T09:49:03.040120+00:00 app[web.1]: Grabbing Submission 1
2015-04-28T09:49:05.056468+00:00 app[web.1]: Grabbing Comment 1
2015-04-28T09:49:05.056661+00:00 app[web.1]: Querying: disappearing spoon
2015-04-28T09:49:05.056790+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "reddit_bot2.py", line 119, in <module>
2015-04-28T09:49:05.056785+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-04-28T09:49:05.056885+00:00 app[web.1]:     main()
2015-04-28T09:49:05.056956+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "reddit_bot2.py", line 76, in main
2015-04-28T09:49:05.057002+00:00 app[web.1]:     rating, desc, link, authors = query_goodreads(comment_text)
2015-04-28T09:49:05.057035+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "reddit_bot2.py", line 93, in query_goodreads
2015-04-28T09:49:05.057071+00:00 app[web.1]:     query = gc.search_books(q, page= 1, search_field= 'all')
2015-04-28T09:49:05.057111+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: GoodreadsClient instance has no attribute 'search_books'
2015-04-28T09:49:06.022454+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-28T09:49:06.005309+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

The main error being an AttributeError.

Searching around, others encounter this error on Django, but the solutions seem to be only for Django, and my script doesn't use it - it does use a Python API wrapper for Goodreads (found [here](http://goodreads.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)). 
I modified the code a bit to try to list down the instance's attributes.

```
print(dir(gc))
```

gc being the GoodreadsClient instance, and it prints this list of attributes

['**doc**', '**init**', '**module**', 'auth_user', 'authenticate', 'author', 'base_url', 'book', 'book_review_stats', 'client_key', 'client_secret', 'find_author', 'find_groups', 'group', 'list_comments', 'list_events', 'owned_book', 'query_dict', 'recent_reviews', 'request', 'request_oauth', 'review', 'search_books', 'user']

which is consistent with the documentation of the API wrapper. But once deployed, it prints

['**doc**', '**init**', '**module**', 'auth_user', 'authenticate', 'author', 'base_url', 'book', 'book_review_stats', 'client_key', 'client_secret', 'find_groups', 'group', 'list_comments', 'list_events', 'owned_book', 'query_dict', 'recent_reviews', 'request', 'request_oauth', 'review', 'user']

Which is missing the 'find_author' and 'search_books' attributes (search_books being the attribute that was giving the error once on heroku). **What's causing these attributes to go missing? Is there a workaround?**

My [script](https://github.com/FatNarwhal/grreviews_bot/blob/master/reddit_bot2.py), if it helps.

Comment: Try checking the version deployed on heroku and compare it to the version you are using locally. Should be as simple as printing or logging `goodreads.__version__` or `client.__version__`

Comment: This has to be the problem. Checking the repo history for goodreads, those two functions were only added 10 days ago

Comment: Damn, good eye! I can't seem to get the version number through either 'goodreads.__version__' or 'client.__version__', but I checked my (local) setup.py and it matches with the latest version. I only deployed it to Heroku yesterday though, and as far as I know I haven't downloaded any new versions - don't know how I could have gotten a different version. Will continue to search. Thanks!

Comment: bah, that's just bad practice on the author's part for not adding a `__version__`. Hope you get it sorted out!